# Get the last 10 events in Eventlog(Application, Secuirty, System) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the the last 10 events in the «EventLog» logs «Application», «Security» and «System» parallelly. I get an error with this message:

> Get-EventLog : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'LogName'"

when running the script. The script works when running with only the logname "Application".

```
Get-Eventlog -Newest 10 -LogName "Application","Security","System"
```

Comment: This is becuase LogName requires a string and you are putting in a array

Answer (score 2):

```
"Application","Security","System" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-Eventlog -Newest 10 -LogName $_ 
}
```

That will get you the 10 most recent events in each log.  If you want the 10 most recent events of all three logs taken together, you will need to do this:

```
"Application","Security","System" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-Eventlog -Newest 10 -LogName $_ 
} | Sort-Object -Property Time -Descending | Select-Object -First 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you are trying, as -LogName requires a string and you are passing an array.

You could accomplish your task by piping an array into a [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) and going through the logs one at a time. The `%{}` is an alias for ForEach-Object

```
"Application","Security","System" | %{Get-Eventlog -Newest 10 -LogName $_}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
How can I restart the Print Spooler daily in powershell by using the ScheduledJob? 

     I tried using : 
Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force

Comment: Hey :) Sadly that is not how StackOverflow works. You need to create a new question and show what you have tried so others can help you. Its kinda of like a place to learn / or troubleshoot but its not a place where we just answer questions not related to the primary question. Again i would open a new question and show what you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Get-eventlog has been replaced by get-winevent.  You'd still have to use foreach to get 10 of each.  Grouping by logname instead of providername might be less annoying.

```
echo Application,Security,System | % { get-winevent $_ -maxevents 10 } | 
  ft -groupby logname
```